# getting xml from URL into variable

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml

I am trying to get an xml feed from a url

```
http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=1230&regionlimit=10000002
```

but seem to be failing miserably. I have tried

- [`new SimpleXMLElement`](http://php.net/SimpleXMLElement),
- [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) and
- `http_get`

Yet none of these seem to echo a nice XML feed when I either `echo` or `print_r`. The end goal is to eventually parse this data but getting it into a variable would sure be a nice start.

I have attached my code below. This is contained within a loop and `$typeID` does in fact give the correct ID as seen above

```
$url = 'http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid='.$typeID.'&regionlimit=10000002';
echo $url."<br />";
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($url);
print_r($xml);
```

I should state that the other strange thing I am seeing is that when I echo $url, i get

```
http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=1230®ionlimit=10000002
```

the `&reg` is the registered trademark symbol. I am unsure if this is "feature" in my browser, or a "feature" in my code

Comment: Which browser are you using? I ask because I'm just wondering about the (side-issue) with the registered trademark symbol.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<?php
$typeID = 1230;
// set feed URL
$url = 'http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid='.$typeID.'&regionlimit=10000002';
echo $url."<br />";
// read feed into SimpleXML object
$sxml = simplexml_load_file($url);

// then you can do
var_dump($sxml);

// And now you'll be able to call `$sxml->marketstat->type->buy->volume` as well as other properties.
echo $sxml->marketstat->type->buy->volume;

// And if you want to fetch multiple IDs:
foreach($sxml->marketstat->type as $type){
    echo $type->buy->volume . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I attempted `$volume = $sxml->buy->volume; echo $volume` however nothing was returned, any idea why?

Comment: @mhopkins321 First make sure that the `$typeID` is defined, and second you should call: `$sxml->marketstat->type->buy->volume` (answer fixed)

Comment: somewhat new to php/xml (obviously) if my url was `http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=1230&typeid=1231&regionlimit=10000002` where there would be two different type id's, where in the line of -> would the id go in?

Comment: @mhopkins321 you can't pass two $typeID's - one of them will run over the other!

Comment: hmmm... that's not a normal HTTP behavior... Let me check.

Comment: my goal here is to query all 30 or so items i'd like to get, so that I only have to hit their API once. if you look at that url in a browser, you can see both item types listed

Comment: wow, i would have never been able to put that together. thanks man. double green checkmark!

Comment: @mhopkins321 my pleasure brother ;) Happy new year!

Answer (score 4):

You need to fetch the data from the URL in order to make an XML object.

```
$url = 'http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid='.$typeID.'&regionlimit=10000002';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents($url));

// pre tags to format nicely
echo '<pre>';
print_r($xml);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: this returns some data that i'm not quite familiar with (though it's probably what truly raw xml looks like?). If wanted to call the node at $xml->sell->average. what would I set my variable to? I attempted `$sell = $xml->sell->average` however that didn't seem to work

Comment: Sorry, changing `var_dump` to `print_r` will give you a more friendly result. To access the sell average, you would want to do `$xml->marketstat->type->sell->average`